# date parsing in java to desire date format

Tags: java

I am trying to do an integration between 2 system,
so there is a datetime field in the source system which has format like
`"dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"` for example- `19-JUN-2017 16:12:30`
but what my target system reads is like `"yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"`
for example- `2017-12-04 19:14:16`

As I am setting a value like

`Tableset.setValue("TRANSACTIONDATE",CSVFILECOLUMN[1], 2L);`

can any one tell me how can I parse the date format in `CSV` file here to set the parsed value in my `TRANSACTIONDATE` field.

Answer (score 0):

Covert your date like this

```
String mydate="19-JUN-2017 16:12:30";
SimpleDateFormat currentFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
SimpleDateFormat newFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
Date d = currentFormat.parse(mydate);
String formattedTime = newFormat.format(d);
```

then calculate difference